# Arranging 3 Bootstrap Cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Page like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       B
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
       C
    </div>
</div>
```

which looks like:

```
------- 
|A|B|C|
-------
```

So if I look at it on a mobile Device, it appears as:

```
---
|A|
|B|
|C|
---
```

Where as I want to make them appear as:

```
-----
|A|C|
| B |
-----
```

A and C are to contain an image each, while B shall contain Text.

I tried:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-8" >
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-2 col-xs-6">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I do not get the desired result. What can i do?

Regards,
GenXCoders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to think "mobile-first"...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-8 col-xs-6">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-2">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/445bg4bb57

Comment: thanks a ton... it works just as i wanted it to... also, i will remember, its "mobile first"...